# Importance of GID and UID?

Tags: linux, administrator, administration

Whether we could hide the presence of a file by modifiying the gid/uid?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is to put the file in a directory and revoke the "r" and "x" permissions on the directory from whomever you don't want.  There is no standard way to hide a file by just modifying the permissions of the file itself.